# Changing content block and updating all emails which contain the block

Tags: marketing-cloud, email-template

I have a number of templates (10+) which use content blocks containing AMPScript. When making changing to the content block itself, those changes aren't reflected in the emails which use the content block unless I remove and re-add the block.

Is there a faster way update the emails with the most up to date version of the block?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use AMPScript to reference an external content block in the email instead of inserting it in content builder. That way updates in the content block will affect all emails that reference that block.

Comment: The problem with this approach is that users will need to trained to use AMPScript build emails

Answer (score 2):

Right now, AMPScript is the only way to do it but we're adding a new feature to handle this in the August release.

Comment: Can you update your answer with a link to this feature?

Comment: You can find info about the Reference Block here: https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_rn_content_builder.htm&type=5

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Content Builder I'm afraid there currently is no way to do this. However, Content Builder is updated with every release of Marketing Cloud so chances are high this feature will be added in the near future.